# How to feed a Tensorflow Dataset with more than two Values to Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a `tf.Dataset` that consists of three seperate entries. This means when I call from my dataset.iterator `get_next()` I get the following values:

```
dataset = inputs(...) # Extracts Data from a TFRecord and preprocesses it
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
sess.run(iterator.initializer)
sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
input_1, label_1, label_2 = iterator.get_next()
```

Furthermore i built a custom loss function so my loss can takes the two labels to compute a single loss even though it has only a single output. This Loss is inspired by [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2121#issuecomment-214551349):

```
def loss_func(label_1, label_2):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):  #  y_true is a dummy that is not used.
        """..."""
    return scalar
return loss
```

I would like to feed my Dataset into the Keras `model.fit(Dataset, ...)` function. However I don't know how Keras handles the three different Values of the Dataset instead of the standard (value, label) pair.
My current guess is that Keras creates an iterator when calling fit going over the entire Dataset. For the iterator it assigns the first value as input x and the second value as label y.

**Which way can I feed my Dataset to the model.fit() function or what alternatives to I have?**

---

The Code looks in the end like this:

```
def loss_func(label_1, label_2):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):  #  y_true is a dummy that is not used.
        """..."""
    return scalar
return loss

model = my_keras_model.get_model(...) # Returns the Keras Model

dataset = inputs(...)
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
sess.run(iterator.initializer)
sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
input_1, label_1, label_2 = iterator.get_next()

loss = loss_func(label_1, label_2)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=loss)

model.fit(???)
# or model.train_on_batch()?
```